# How do you get the location of the mouse and place a element beside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do you get the location of a mouse and then place a HTML element beside it?
For example, If i have a `<textarea>` and i want a toolbar to appear by the mouse when it is hovered over, how would i do this?

Comment: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

Comment: @JakeGould, I was going to post my code but all i was really looking for was the attributes needed to get the position so i decided my coding was not needed. But, jqueryrocks gave me everything i needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the x and y coordinates with `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` in your mousemove function for the textarea.

```
$('textarea#myText').mouseenter(function(event) {
  $('#toolbar').show();
});
$('textarea#myText').mousemove(function(event) {
  var left = event.pageX + 20;
  var top = event.pageY + 20;
  $('#toolbar').css('left', left).css('top', top);
});
$('textarea#myText').mouseleave(function(event) {
  $('#toolbar').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! By your username i suspect you like JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be found here:
[HTML-Tooltip position relative to mouse pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702867/html-tooltip-position-relative-to-mouse-pointer)

Look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJf8q/2/) for more info.

```
var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip span');

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    var x = (e.clientX + 20) + 'px',
        y = (e.clientY + 20) + 'px';

    for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
        tooltips[i].style.top = y;
        tooltips[i].style.left = x;
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 for using raw JavaScript instead of JQuery

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/TL7V7/5/

```
yourText = document.getElementById('yourText');
yourToolbar = document.getElementById('yourToolbar');
yourText.addEventListener('mouseenter',function(e){
    setTimeout(function(){
        yourToolbar.style.opacity=opacity_hi;
        //this CSS3 renders faster:
        yourToolbar.style.transform='translate('+(1000+mx-10)+'px,'+(1000+my+10)+'px)';
        yourToolbar.style.webkitTransform='translate('+(1000+mx-10)+'px,'+(1000+my+10)+'px)';
    },hide_delay/2);
    //...
});
yourText.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
    mx=e.pageX;
    my=e.pageY;
    //...
});
```

See the link above.

Comment: Thank you as well! This is why i love Stack Overflow. You get so many great answers so quickly!