# Create interactive drill-down map

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, maps

I've created an HTML map using images and polygons as well as javascript to create an interactive drill-down map similar to the following ones which use flash:

https://www.spitogatos.gr/

http://www.xe.gr/property/

How would you go about creating such a map without using flash?

The way I've done it now is difficult to manage and expand, as it relies on the images and coordinates a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use svg to make the map.

Check this link : https://parall.ax/blog/view/2985/tutorial-creating-an-interactive-svg-map

Demo : https://parall.ax/examples/svg_map

And use some javascript to display the tooltip : [HTML-Tooltip position relative to mouse pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702867/html-tooltip-position-relative-to-mouse-pointer)

I hope this help :)