# EventLister arguments required error inside forEach (tooltip)

Tags: javascript, foreach, mouseevent, mouseover

I have been trying to build a simpler JavaScript-based tooltip. After much trial and error and a lot of searching, I found Daniel Imms [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15703312/12822663).

I have been working on this on my [codepen](https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/oNLaYXp?). I also have an [earlier codepen](https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/OJXBbLr) that has Daniel Imms' original JS intact and shows no errors in the console.

I changed the structure to use a forEach to add the event listeners and used the arrow function to try to make the syntax efficient. Unfortunately, I have done something wrong and I didn't pick it up at first because the tool-tip is partially working just with HTML and CSS. I still need the Javascript to control the X Y position hardcoded but I don't want it to follow the cursor.
The errors I can see in the `codepen` are:

> TypeError: EventTarget.addEventListener: At least 2 arguments required, but only 1 passed

and

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'

All assistance is greatly appreciated.

as well as:

> "message": "TypeError: tooltips is undefined",

Please see my code attached:

```js
var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip span').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
    tooltips.style.top = '40px';
     tooltips.style.left = '80px';   
  })
})
```

```css
.tooltip {
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
}
.tooltip span {
    display:none;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.infobox
{
background: pink;
padding: 0.5%;    
width: 290px;
height: 40px;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="tooltip">
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/j354374/fed-scripting/dfeae751ff2e30ba8963f4676ce6c3b857678992/forms/images/info-circle5.svg" alt="info">
    <span>
      <div class="infobox">TEST</div>
    </span>
</a>


<a class="tooltip">
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/j354374/fed-scripting/dfeae751ff2e30ba8963f4676ce6c3b857678992/forms/images/info-circle5.svg" alt="info">
    <span>
      <div class="infobox">TEST2</div>
    </span>
</a>

<a class="tooltip">
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/j354374/fed-scripting/dfeae751ff2e30ba8963f4676ce6c3b857678992/forms/images/info-circle5.svg" alt="info">
    <span>
      <div class="infobox">TEST3</div>
    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning return value of `forEach` to `tooltips` and it always is `undefined`.

You need to assign value of `document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip span')` to `tooltips` variable and implement `forEach` as follows.

```js
var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip span');
tooltips.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
    tooltips.style.top = '40px';
     tooltips.style.left = '80px';   
  })
})
```

```css
.tooltip {
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
}
.tooltip span {
    display:none;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.infobox
{
background: pink;
padding: 0.5%;    
width: 290px;
height: 40px;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="tooltip">
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/j354374/fed-scripting/dfeae751ff2e30ba8963f4676ce6c3b857678992/forms/images/info-circle5.svg" alt="info">
    <span>
      <div class="infobox">TEST</div>
    </span>
</a>


<a class="tooltip">
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/j354374/fed-scripting/dfeae751ff2e30ba8963f4676ce6c3b857678992/forms/images/info-circle5.svg" alt="info">
    <span>
      <div class="infobox">TEST2</div>
    </span>
</a>

<a class="tooltip">
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/j354374/fed-scripting/dfeae751ff2e30ba8963f4676ce6c3b857678992/forms/images/info-circle5.svg" alt="info">
    <span>
      <div class="infobox">TEST3</div>
    </span>
</a>
```