# Can I use html5 data attribute in HTML select box element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Any idea can I use .data attribute in HTML select box?I red HTML5 documents but I didn't find any information that could help me.

Is it legal:

```
<span>Select depatament</span>
<span>
    <select id="department" onchange="EnableSelectBox(this)" data-spacing="10cm">
        <option selected disabled>-Select-</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly fine. But, `onchange="EnableSelectBox(this)"` isn't that pretty! [More Info](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute--webdesign-9642)

Comment: You can use data-attributes pretty much everywhere. You can also [use self-made custom attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25813336/1654265) pretty much everywhere (but try choosing names that won't be introduced later by the W3C specs, or you'll need to fix your code).

Comment: [Every HTML element may have any number of custom data attributes specified, with any value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#custom-data-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it fine to use data in Html5 tag. I don't know why you want to use in such a way, but you can use it.

for example like this

`$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('#department').data('spacing'));
});`

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wh4sakam/)

Answer (score 1):

[Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

> Any attribute on any element whose attribute name starts with data- is a data attribute.

To answer the question: Yes. You can use data attributes on any element.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine. Test in [JS](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) using:

```
alert(document.getElementById("department").getAttribute("data-spacing"))
```