# Tooltip text testing in Sahi

Tags: testing, automation, sahi

How to test Tooltip text by mouse hovering in Sahi tool?
I have to hover by mouse on a graph and test the text appear in tooltip after hovering. But I am not able to do with Sahi. Please tell how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the topic on tooltip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117073/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-a-div) . If that is what you are trying to do then it is easy to find the particular element and get the title attribute.

```
var $myelm = _div("Id or Text");
var $attributeName = "title";
var $tooltip = _getAttribute($myelm, $attributeName);
```

Answer (score 1):

To automate hover action using sahi tool, you may use their api '_mouseOver'. e.g _mouseOver(_cell("cell15"));