# Show Guideline Tooltip when hover input field in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I need a guideline tooltip when the user hover the input fields like username field, password field..etc.,

The guideline tooltip must have a short text, close button and a button 'NEXT'. When the button Next is clicked, the current tooltip will close then another pop-up tooltip will appear that proceeds to step 2 in the next field.

Instead of using plug-ins, It must be just HTML and CSS or with Javascript/Jquery.

Comment: use jquery ui tooltip. Refer http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp. It might help you

Comment: instead, you can use the popover. show the popover on hover. you can easily style the popover contents as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a tooltip to a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117073/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-a-div)