# Show data-attribute class from other class hovering

Tags: html, css, custom-data-attribute

I´m using the following tooltip hint from [this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117073/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-a-div/25813336#25813336)

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5gyvyhrc/)

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.area1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.area2 {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.area3 {
  background-color: violet;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

[tooltip]:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(tooltip);
  opacity: 0;
}

[tooltip]:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <div class='area1' tooltip='this is area 1'>
  </div>
  <div class='area2' tooltip='this is area 2'>
  </div>
  <div class='area3' tooltip='this is area 3'>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to show the tooltip only when hovering the area, not when hovering the tooltip (as shown).

I´ve tried:

```
.area1:hover [tooltip] {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

and

```
.area1:hover [tooltip]:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Both cases I had no success.

Comment: Your implementation similar to this one - see if you can figure out the difference https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Comment: Why, @acoder? Just because it's simple?

Comment: Could you please point me where in the rules or meta says such a thing, @acoder? I know sometimes people answer in comments but IMHO a real answer (even more an accepted one) marks the question as completed so it's more useful to others.

Comment: In fact, @acoder, if you check the section **When *shouldn't* I comment?** in [Comment Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) you'll see that, on the contrary, answering in comments isn't a good practice. And it says nothing about the complexity of the answer.

Comment: okay okay!!!! Sorry!!

Comment: No problem at all, @acoder :) Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Thanks- Same to you. Please check my this answer what's people said https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208046/toggle-the-div-when-link-is-cliked/47208561#47208561

Comment: @JordiNebot please check..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159252/discussion-between-jordi-nebot-and-acoder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on `[tooltip]::before`. It does exactly what it seems:

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.area {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

#area1 { background-color: red; }
#area2 { background-color: orange; }
#area3 { background-color: violet; }

[tooltip]::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(tooltip);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

[tooltip]:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="area1" class="area" tooltip="this is area 1"></div>
  <div id="area2" class="area" tooltip="this is area 2"></div>
  <div id="area3" class="area" tooltip="this is area 3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great and simple. Thanks!