# How to join after cornerRadius is provided for piecharts in recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am using recharts and I am trying to create a pie chart with only the radius at the edges of the chart. What I get is the following. Similar to that in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktbp6gr5/).

```
<PieChart width={800} height={400} onMouseEnter={this.onPieEnter}>

    <Pie
      data={data} 
      cx={420} 
      cy={200} 
      startAngle={180}
      endAngle={0}
      cornerRadius={40}
      innerRadius={60}
      outerRadius={80} 
      data={data}
     fill="#8884d8"
    />
  </PieChart>
```

[image]

As you can see that the corner radius is added to each of the data elements. What is want is something like the image below. (Sorry for my bad editing skills)

[image]

Is something like this possible in recharts?

If not something like having a total value could also work for me. What I mean is that let's say the total value to be shown in the chart is 100 and the data I provide is 50. Then 50% of the data is shown in the chart as some color and the reset 50% is greyed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a work around for this and it will help you out. I will suggest you to create 2 Pies: `one with rounded corners` and `one with pointed corners`. And rest all data same

- for the pointed corners, make their colour transparent except for index 0 and length - 1
- for the rounded corners, do the reverse

You will get this kind of output:

[image]

Here is the JS fiddle for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/kmfby50o/

Visually you will see what you want. And for the functionality like onClick etc, apply that to second `<Pie>`. Since it overlaps the first one, that will also be taken care of.

```
const { PieChart, Pie, Sector, Cell } = Recharts;
const data = [{ name: 'Group A', value: 400 }, { name: 'Group B', value: 300 },
{ name: 'Group C', value: 300 }, { name: 'Group D', value: 200 }];
const COLORS = ['#0088FE', '#00C49F', '#FFBB28', '#FF8042'];

const RADIAN = Math.PI / 180;

const SimplePieChart = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <PieChart width={800} height={400} onMouseEnter={this.onPieEnter}>

                <Pie
                    data={data}
                    cx={420}
                    cy={200}
                    startAngle={180}
                    endAngle={0}
                    cornerRadius={40}
                    innerRadius={60}
                    outerRadius={80}
                    fill="#8884d8"
                    paddingAngle={-5}
                >
                    {
                        data.map((entry, index) => <Cell fill={index === 0 || index === data.length - 1 ? COLORS[index % COLORS.length] : 'transparent'} />)
                    }
                </Pie>
                <Pie
                    data={data}
                    cx={420}
                    cy={200}
                    startAngle={180}
                    endAngle={0}
                    cornerRadius={0}
                    innerRadius={60}
                    outerRadius={80}
                    fill="#8884d8"
                >
                    {
                        data.map((entry, index) => <Cell fill={index === 0 || index === data.length - 1 ? 'transparent' : COLORS[index % COLORS.length]} />)
                    }
                </Pie>
            </PieChart>
        );
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(
    <SimplePieChart />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sunil. I just had one question and I will accept the answer. Can the curve at the orange section be removed?

Comment: The slight curve between orange and yellow, that one? Yes! In the 1st `<Pie>`, there is `paddingAngle={-5}` make it to `-10` or `-15` and you will get the desired effect

Comment: One question I had is that is it possible to add a single tooltip to the pie chart. I mean that a single tooltip needs to be shown for the entire pie chart and the tooltip needs to follow the mouse pointer. I will be happy to ask a new question if you want.

Comment: One more question. Looks like this solution does not work if there are just 2 data points. I tried doing so and the edges still seemed to curve

Comment: For tooltip, I am not sure as of now, will post here if I get something relevant (or you can try posting new question so someone else might be able to help you out). You can try wrapping whole chart in div with title as given in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7117107/6487887). This will give you native tooltip

Comment: No worries sunil. I think i will just break down the largest section into two. so there will be 3 sections and there seems to be no problem  when there are 3 sections.

Comment: And it seems that you can pass stroke property to the `Cell`. If stroke and fill are same there will be no gap between the two and they will seem one.

Comment: I dont think the  tootltip solution with the div will work. I just need the tooltip over the chart. Thanks i will try to research for this a little bit.

Answer (score 4):

There is one possible way of doing it as follows,
You can pass a prop named as paddingAngle={0} to the PieChart component. Find the code below.

```
<Pie
      data={data} 
      cx={120} 
      cy={200} 
      innerRadius={60}
      outerRadius={80} 
      fill="#8884d8"
      paddingAngle={0}
    >
        {
        data.map((entry, index) => <Cell fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]}/>)
      }
    </Pie>
```

The results you will achieve will be like shown in image below
[image]

Source fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vkpwm2st/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i only needed a semi circle not a full circle.

Comment: Use below code to get Semi Circle

<Pie
          data={data} 
          cx={420} 
          cy={200} 
          startAngle={180}
          endAngle={0}
          innerRadius={60}
          outerRadius={80} 
          fill="#8884d8"
          paddingAngle={0}
        >
         {
           data.map((entry, index) => <Cell fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]}/>)
          }
        </Pie>

Comment: Thanks for the response. But looks like this does not have have the rounded corners at the edges like that in the picture above. I just need the rounded corners at the edges.

Comment: You can simply add paddingAngle={0}  prop to your shared component in question.

Comment: Okay i just tried the solution in this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ktbp6gr5/   . Can you please edit it.

Comment: Visit: https://jsfiddle.net/jordc7xq/
I have edited the source code there as you asked, Now you can give paddingAngle prop in negative to overlap the pie chart.

Comment: Thanks for the response but is there no way to remove the cornerRadius completely. The overlap really doesnot look nice.

Comment: You can set cornerRadius={0}

Comment: But that will remove the corner radius from the edges as well. I just need the corner radius at the edges.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple. Just set the `paddingAngle` attribute to a negative value like so:

```
<PieChart width={800} height={400} onMouseEnter={this.onPieEnter}>

    <Pie
      data={data} 
      cx={420} 
      cy={200} 
      startAngle={180}
      endAngle={0}
      cornerRadius={40}
      innerRadius={60}
      outerRadius={80} 
      data={data}
      paddingAngle={-20}
     fill="#8884d8"
    />
</PieChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Pie chart you should use Radial bar chart provided you are using only one sector for your pie

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).